# Install Windows 2000 Server on new Dell hardware

Tags: hardware, windows, dell-poweredge, windows-server-2000

I'll be contacting Dell as well with this question but I was wondering if anyone has had any experience installing Windows 2000 Server on a new Dell Rack server? I'm looking at either the Dell Poweredge series. Either a R410, R610, or R710.

Additionally, virtualization is not an option as Hyper-V cannot assign more than one virtual core to a Win2000 VM. I really just need to know if this is possible or not.

Comment: With W2K being EOL a few years back I'd be shocked if you found something current that did support it.

Comment: This is unsupported, Windows 2000 is out of support years ago.

Comment: @pauska: I'm not asking if it's a supported product. I'm asking if it's possible to install it on the above hardware. Could you please be more clear with your answer (if you have one). Thanks.

Comment: The reason we're pointing it out is because there isnt much point (or value to future visitors) to use time on figuring this out. The answer is also pretty obvious (see joeqwerty's response), it all matters if you can find drivers or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you're likely to run into is with drivers, most probably the RAID controller and NIC drivers. My suggestion would be to take a look at the available drivers for those models at http://support.dell.com and see if W2K drivers are available.